# how to use role in mvc identity 2.1.0

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I want to introduce the identity role to my login page .the user after entering username and password should select a dropdownlist of roles (superuser-admin-user).how could that happen?

Comment: What stage are you in? have you created role manager?

Comment: actually I don't understand the role provider enough to actually start coding.so I was looking for some help in explaining and coding.I have doing reading for the past 2 days and still a mess.can you please help me.assume im starting from scartch that is the default mvc project

Comment: at first I thought it is a simple create database with the role attribute as we used to do in vb.net but seems not like that

Comment: Let me know if you need any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class to manage roles, that would be something like ApplicationRoleManager

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

Then you need to create instance of ApplicationRoleManager on owin startup. Add below code inside the ConfigureAuth method on Owin startup. App_Start >> Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

Now you have all setup for manage your roles. Make sure you have added roles to your 'AspNetRoles' table

Then you can retrieve roles as below inside the Login (Get) action

```
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var roleManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();

        var list = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Name");

        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Then you can get roles in the Login view. After that populate dropdownList with roles. Your rasor script will look like below.

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id="RoleDdlLabel" class="col-md-2 control-label">Select Role</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("RoleList", ViewBag.Roles as SelectList)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
```

I hope you can finish the saving part by posting the selected role with other model values. You can change the LoginViewModel to include roles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: lots of errors.can we chat via skype please.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is 100% working example. I have put it on GitHub,  https://github.com/TechWhizIn/asp.net-Identity-framework-rolemanager-sample

Comment: this is 100% working true. but shouldn't the role selection be in the registration page so that when the user log in with wrong role he will be announced wrong role else he will be redirected to the correct page.where is that happening?I don't see role associated to user registered

Comment: Mohommad, have you forgot your question, I have answered for your question, thats all, you can use this code to get what you want as a developer.

Comment: sorry I got mixed up with another question I already asked that is how to associate the role to the user.is that possible.and really thanks for your help.but im really new to mvc trying to work out something useful

Comment: No worries, That would be the same, but you can't let user's to select roles when they are registering , am I correct? What is your requirement? Explain it more in your actual question.

Comment: the superuser is authorized to create admins only,so the superuser create the role as well but only admin roles.and the admin after login, he is authorized to create users as well.so the superuser is allowed to create admins, and admins are allowed to create users.no user can create credentials for himself unless enduser. so the select role is specific for each create.is that clear enough?

Comment: Added some answers on actual question.